# How to set series expression when you do not have any series when creating bar chart in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, bar-chart

I have created a bar chart in iReport Designer 5.1.0. I want to show some ips at x axis and the occurrence of each of these ips at y axis. The bar chart must have a single color but when I run it bars have different colors with each other. I think series expression has to be empty, and I have to put $F{ip} in category expression and $F{occurrence} in value expression, but series expression has to be filled because it is not optional.

It would be great if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your series expression, using quotes you can just specify something like a name or anything relative to the chart. For e.g,"Ip v/s Occurrence". Basically have a string value in there. This will be displayed as a legend. You would get the chart in single color.

Comment: Thanks. Rashmi, I have created a horizontal bar chart. Do you know how I can locate the x axis at the bottom of the bar chart?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I didnt understand the question.

Comment: Rashmi, when I changed orientation of the bar chart from vertical to horizontal, the x axis line is at the top of the bar chart. I want to change its location to the bottom. Unfortunately, I cannot find the way to do this simple task. :(

Answer (score 0):

change the orientation again back to vertical. Click the barchart and choose the properties to be orientation:vertical.
Hope thats what you meant